# получить имя собственного(открытого) файла Access через VBA

Tags: vba, access, visual-basic, ms-access

Подскажите пожалуйста, как определить имя файла. Есть файл Access. Нужно при его открытии получить его же собственное имя. В ворде и экселе есть встроенные методы(не работают в аксессе), но в аксессе подобного не нашел. Может ктото сталкивался. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Через объект CurrentProject

```
Sub ApplicationInformation() 
 'Имя и тип текущего проекта
 Debug.Print Application.CurrentProject.FullName 
 Debug.Print Application.CurrentProject.ProjectType 
 Dim fso as new FileSystemObject
 fileName = fso.GetFileName(Application.CurrentProject.FullName)
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !!! теперь нужно только распарсить)

Comment: Добавил извлечение имени

Comment: мне нужна была только эта строчка Application.CurrentProject.FullName . Дальше я просто убрал все лишнее, распарсив строку и выдернул имя файла без расширения. Спасибо за наводку